# How to avoid orphan dynamic text in an HTML

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have a fixed width HTML page that has some dynamic copy/text  injected into it. The text should be allowed to wrap, but not produce an orphan

e.g

> Hi [first name], would you like to play a game?

Problem is since the [first name] is dynamic and could be any length, I can't seem to avoid sometimes having an orphan

e.g

> Hi Guy-with-really-long-name, would you like to play a
>
> game?

I can't use css "`white-space: nowrap;`"   as it should be allowed to wrap, just not with an orphan.

I would also like a solution that will work on HTML email as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `white-space: nowrap` for the last (e.g. four) words

```
Hi Guy-with-really-long-name, would you like 
<span style="white-space: nowrap">to play a game?</span>
```